# Nodejs implementing socket cluster dont work my sockets

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I'm trying to implementing `cluster` on nodejs and using `Socket.io` in my application, after some search and introduced about that and finding [sticky-socket-cluster](https://github.com/PROGrand/sticky-socket-cluster) i try to use that, here is sample code which i use the documentetion of library, but `login` socket not working and dont print log

```
require('sticky-socket-cluster/replace-console')();

var options = {
    workers     : require('os').cpus().length, // total workers (default: cpu cores count).
    first_port  : 8000, // 8000, 8001 are worker's ports (default: 8000).
    proxy_port  : 3000, // default (5000).
    session_hash: function (req, res) {
        return req.connection.remoteAddress;
    },

    no_sockets: false // allow socket.io proxy (default: false).
};

require('sticky-socket-cluster')(options, start);

function start(port) {
    var express = require('express');
    var http    = require('http');
    var app     = express();
    var server  = http.Server(app);
    var socket  = require('socket.io')(server);

    socket.on('connection', function (socket) {
        console.log("socket.io connection handler...");
    });

    socket.on('login', function (data) {
        console.log(data.username);
    });

    server.listen(port, function () {
        console.log('Express and socket.io listening on port ' + port);
    });

}
```